# Multipass VM not reachable via specific http ports from host

Tags: macos, kubernetes, microk8s, skaffold, multipass

I'm running an Ubuntu VM with multipass hyperkit do run microk8s. Within the VM all things checkout and available with skaffold/kubectl port forwarding. For instance:

```
$ multipass list
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
microk8s-vm             Running           192.168.64.2     Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                                          10.0.1.1
                                          172.17.0.1
                                          10.1.254.64
```

`Port forwarding service/my-app in namespace default, remote port 80 -> 127.0.0.1:4503`

Within the VM:`curl localhost:4503` ✅

From the host: `curl 192.168.64.2:4503`

I know the VM is reachable on port 80 because `curl 192.168.64.2` returns default ngnix not found page. *FWIW I never installed ngnix and the service doesn't seem to be running /cannot turn it off.*

I've been at this for a day and I'm stumped. I even tried the Vbox driver and manually configured a bridge adapter. I even created my own adapter...

```
$ multipass exec -- microk8s-vm sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/netplan/60-bridge.yaml" <<EOF
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:                  # this is the interface name from above
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:       # this is needed so the default gateway
        route-metric: 200    # remains with the first interface
  version: 2
EOF
$ multipass exec microk8s-vm sudo netplan apply
```

How can I reach this VM from the host?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue right now, no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access your pod ip /portlike this.
If you want to access your pods port over the nodes ip address, you need to define a service type NodePort and then use ipaddressOfNode:NodePort.

```
curl http://ipaddressOfNode:NodePort
```

With port-forward you must use the localhost of your host system.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/myservice 8000:yourServicePort
```

then

```
curl http://localhost:8000
```